# How to sort and display an object based on its key value pairs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am really new to the vanilla JavaScript so bear with me.

So I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```html
var partyGuests =[
    {
        firstName: "Wayne",
        lastName: "Gretzky",
        items: "birthday cake"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Emily",
        lastName: "Janeson",
        items: "balloons"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Gordon",
        lastName: "Ramsey",
        items: "balloons"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Jasmine",
        lastName: "Quaker",
        items: "birthday cake"
    }
]
```

If they are bringing "balloons", they would be appended to  `<div id="balloonGroup">` and if they are bringing "birthday cake", they would be appended to `<div id="cakeGroup">`

I want my whole array of objects to be displayed on the page (including name, last name, and item), but displayed in the div based on the items that they bring.

I have tried using map, forEach, and filter, but I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Here is what I tried, but I cannot figure out a way to sort them into the appropriate div's.

```html
let guests = partyGuests.map(res=>{
    return res;
})

function groupAssignment(value, index){
    const FirstName = `<li>Name: ${value.firstName}</li>`;
    const LastName = `<li> Last Name: ${value.lastName}</li>`;
    const Item = `<li>Item: ${value.item}</li>`;
    $("#1").append(firstName, lastName, Item);
}

guests.forEach(groupAssignment);
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I have added a sample of my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to simply loop through the array and fill the content inside the `div` having respective `id`:

```js
var partyGuests =[
    {
        firstName: "Wayne",
        lastName: "Gretzky",
        items: "birthday cake"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Emily",
        lastName: "Janeson",
        items: "balloons"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Gordon",
        lastName: "Ramsey",
        items: "balloons"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Jasmine",
        lastName: "Quaker",
        items: "birthday cake"
    }
];
partyGuests.forEach((obj)=>{
  if(obj.items === 'balloons'){
    $('#balloonGroup').append(
      obj.firstName + ' ' + obj.lastName + ' '
      + obj.items + '<br>'
    );
  }
  
  if(obj.items === 'birthday cake'){
   $('#cakeGroup').append(
       obj.firstName + ' ' + obj.lastName + ' '
       + obj.items + '<br>'
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="balloonGroup"></div>
<div id="cakeGroup"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.forEach` in your code as you just need to iterate over all the array elements.

Steps taken here are:

- Iterate on the array elements.
- Build an HTML string, which you want to append.
- Get the selector to which you want to append based on `items` value.
- Append html string to the selector using `.append()`

```js
var partyGuests = [{
    firstName: "Wayne",
    lastName: "Gretzky",
    items: "birthday cake"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Emily",
    lastName: "Janeson",
    items: "balloons"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Gordon",
    lastName: "Ramsey",
    items: "balloons"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Jasmine",
    lastName: "Quaker",
    items: "birthday cake"
  }
];

partyGuests.forEach(
  el => {
    var _html = '<p><strong>First Name:</strong>' + el.firstName + '<br>' +
      '<strong>Last Name:</strong>' + el.lastName + '<br>' +
      '<strong>Items:</strong>' + el.items + '<br></p>';

    var elem = "";
    if (el.items === "birthday cake")
      elem = '#cakeGroup';
    else if (el.items === "balloons")
      elem = '#balloonGroup';

    $(elem).append(_html);

  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="balloonGroup">
  <h3>Balloons</h3>
</div>

<div id="cakeGroup">
  <h3>Cakes</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<partyGuests.length; i++){
  if (partyGuests[i].items == "birthday cake") {
   //append to cakeGroup here 
  } else if (partyGuests[i].items == "balloons") {
   //append to balloonGroup
  }
}
```

loop over the array of guests and check the items property